# Maximum recursion depth exceed while doing DFS in python3, not solved by increasing limit

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, depth-first-search

I wrote up a program which counts the size of the 5 largest SCC's in a given graph.
The number of nodes in the graph is 875714.
Following is the basic DFS code I'm using  in the problem. (Both functions are methods in a class)

```
def DFSloop(self):
    exp = [False] * (self.size + 1)

    for i in range(1,(self.size + 1)):
        if exp[i] == False:
            self.DFS(i, exp) 

def DFS(self, s, exp):
    exp[s] = True
    for vertex in self.g[s]:
        if exp[vertex] == False:
            self.DFS(vertex, exp)
```

Basically DFS has to recurse a lot as number of nodes and edges is huge.
It showed the following error even after setting the recursion limit to 10,000

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Then upon increasing the limit to 100,000, it showed:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

And the system crashed.
Any help in overcoming the situation?

Answer (score 1):

I overcame a similar issue by using a stack instead of using recursion.

Example:

```
def fib(n):
    stack = [n]
    s = 0
    while len(stack) > 0:
        n = stack.pop()
        if n < 2:
            s += n
        else:
            stack.append(n-1)
            stack.append(n-2)

    return s
```

Comment: who said imperative programs cannot be beautiful?